# How can I reference cousin objects in scons?

Tags: scons

How can I get objects that are built under separate SConscripts in my program correctly? I have a directory structure that looks similar to this:

```
SConstruct
|
|---- moduleA
|     |
|     ----Sconscript
|     ----src
|         |-- sourceA1.cpp
|         |-- sourceA2.cpp
|     ----build
|         |-- sourceA1.o
|         |-- sourceA2.o
|    
|---- moduleB
|     |
|     ----Sconscript
|     ----src
|         |-- sourceB1.cpp
|         |-- sourceB2.cpp
|     ----build
|         |-- sourceB1.o
|         |-- sourceB2.o
| 
|---- Program
      |
      ----SConscript
      ----src
          | -- main.cpp
```

moduleA's SConscript might look like this (moduleB is similar):

```
moduleEnv = env.Clone()
srcFiles = [ 'src/sourceA1.cpp', 'src/sourceA2.cpp' ]

obj = moduleEnv.Object(srcFiles)
```

In my Program, I need to use the object files to build. I don't want to use a bunch of hard coded paths to do this. Is there any way that the SConscript for the program can reference the objects of the modules?

Program's SConscript

```
progEnv = env.Clone()

objectsList = [ Objects from the modules ] # Is this possible, or is the a better way?

prog = progEnv.Program('myprogram', [ objectList, 'src/main.cpp'])
```

Comment: The common way of dealing with bunches of objects in different directory trees is to put them into libraries - then there's only one for each to refer to. Would that work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Any variable you define in an SConscript can be `Export()`ed so other SConscripts can pick it up (via `Import()`).  The export space is global. In your example for moduleA's SConscript, after the call to `Object`, `obj` holds a list of Nodes (even though in the majority of cases that list has only one entry - here it would be two). A node is SCons' internal representation of an object participating in the build, and it's prefectly fine to use those to refer to built objects - and means you shouldn't have path problems, because SCons always knows how to locate a node.  You can collect those and export them. I would probably do one per module, so perhaps:

```py
obj = moduleEnv.Object(srcFiles)
moduleEnv.Export(moduleAobj=obj)
```

Then your main SConscript can look like:

```py
SConscript("moduleA/SConscript")
Import("moduleAobj")
SConscript("moduleB/SConscript")
Import("moduleBobj")

objects = Flatten([moduleAobj, moduleBobj])
```

that's untested but hopefully a starting point, at least.

Comment: Guess should add, the SConscript can also `Return()` something and the calling script can just collect that, so you don't even necessarily have to Export/Import if there's only one value an SConscript needst to pass back.